# Counting number of occurrences in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My task is to find the number of occurrences of late timesheet submissions for each employee in our database. There are two tables which I have primarily been looking at, but I'm having trouble putting the two together and coming up with a decent view of the `COUNT` of occurrences and the employee ID for which they are associated with.

I have created this query which provides me with the `EmployeeID` for each occurrence.

```
SELECT db.Employee.EmployeeID 
FROM db.LateTimesheets
INNER JOIN db.Employee ON Employee.LastName = LateTimesheets.LastName AND Employee.FirstName = Late Timesheets.FirstName
```

Now, with this simple query I have a view of the `EmployeeID` repeated however many times these incidents have occured. However, what I ultimately want to end up with is a table that displays a count for each occurance, along with the `EmployeeID` for which this count is associated with.

I would assume I would need to use the `COUNT()` function to count the amount of rows for each `EmployeeID`, and then select that value along with `EmployeeID`. However, I am having trouble structuring the subquery correctly, and everything I have tried thus far has only generated errors with MS SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler version of `usr`'s answer would be the following which avoids the construction of the derived table:

```
Select db.Employee.EmployeeID, Count( db.LateTimesheets.somecolumn ) As Total
From db.Employee 
    Left Join db.LateTimesheets
        On LateTimesheets.LastName  = Employee.LastName
            And Late Timesheets.FirstName = Employee.FirstName
Group By db.Employee.EmployeeID
```

Comment: This works for one table to count, but does not compose if you want to do multiple joins and multiple subcounts. It is more of a coincidence that it works.

Comment: @usr - It is not a coincidence that it works. It works given the parameters of the problem presented. This can work with multiple joins by simply using `Count(Distinct(...`. In this problem, we are only told of two tables. If there were 20 tables, that would elicit a different solution such that this approach (and your approach) would need to change.

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood the question, but wouldn't `GROUP BY` solve your problem?

```
SELECT COUNT(db.LateTimesheets.somecolumn), db.Employee.EmployeeID 
FROM db.LateTimesheets
INNER JOIN db.Employee ON Employee.LastName = LateTimesheets.LastName 
    AND Employee.FirstName = Late Timesheets.FirstName
GROUP BY db.Employee.EmployeeID
```

Just replace `somecolumn` with the name of a column that's actually in the table.

Comment: Does not return rows for which the join has no rows. I guess the OP wants to have a count of 0 then.

Comment: @usr We can guess all we like, it's up for them to say. If they don't care about those without late timesheets (and I don't see why they would), then this should do everything they need.

Comment: I attempted a query similar to what Anthony posted, and it seems to be spitting out some good looking data. I think I should go review what the GROUP BY command actually does, but it looks like this was the answer I was looking for. "usr", can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: I see what you guys are saying. As this functionality will later be put together to implement an administrative tracking tool, I may need to take into account those EmployeeIDs with no late submissions. Is there an easy way to do this by modifying my current query?

Comment: @Burzum619 If you need a list of **all** employees, with a count of 0 for those with no late timesheets, then usr's answer should do that. Though personally I can't see any real use for providing that information.

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.*, isnull(lt.Count, 0) as Count
from Employee e
left join (
 select LastName, count(*) as Count from LateTimesheets
) LateTimesheets lt on e.LastName = lt.LastName
```

The trick is to do the grouping in a derived table. You don't want to group everything, just the LateTimesheets.

We need a left join to still get employees with no LateTimesheets.